# Boundary conditions on conical deficit AdS geometry

Tags: anti-de-sitter-spacetime

The conical deficit global AdS$_3$ geometry is given by

$$ds^{2} = - \cosh^{2}\rho\ dt^{2} + d\rho^{2} + \sinh^{2}\rho\ d\varphi^{2}, \qquad 0 \leq \varphi < 2\pi(1-4Gm'),$$

where $0 \leq 1-4Gm' < 1$, and $0 \leq \rho < \infty$.

---

Does a finite boundary condition $0 \leq \rho < \rho_c$ change the inequality $0 \leq \varphi < 2\pi(1-4Gm')$ in any way?

My hunch is that there is no change  as the $\phi$ coordinate and the $\rho$ coordinate are independent.